# filepicker.io - Supported file types in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, filepicker.io

I've been looking around the filepicker.io documentation trying to figure out exactly what file types are supported without any luck, because I'm working on an ios app that is integrated with it.  Additionally, is there a quick way to figure out if the file is an image, video, or other type of file?  Filepicker gives back a response url, with the key/value pair:

> FPPickerControllerMediaType = type;

however, type is of the form public.jpeg or public.mp4 etc.  Without knowing the exact file types supported, it would be hard to parse through the various types a given file might be to figure out exactly how to handle it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QLPreviewController to check if the file is something that can be launched.

Here is the documentation

[+ (BOOL) canPreviewItem: (id < QLPreviewItem >) item](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/QLPreviewController/canPreviewItem%3a)